# print out some children from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I want to display some data from Firebase. I have a node that has a bunch of posts named posts.

```
Database.database().reference().child("main").child("posts")
```

using the above code allows me to print out all of the posts in the posts node. However, I don't want to print out all of the posts, I want to print out some posts. 
I want to print some posts based on their post id, how do I print out multiple posts?

**EDIT**

```
var postingID: String?
var posts = NSMutableArray()

  func loadDetails(){
    Database.database().reference().child("main").child("users").child(screenName!).child("bookmarks").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in


        if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {


             for testingkey in postsDictionary.keys {
               Database.database().reference().child("main").child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if snapshot.exists() {
                        for child in snapshot.children {
                            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                            if snap.hasChildren() {
                                if let id = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "id").value as? String, id == testingkey {
                                    print(snap.value!)
                                    self.posts.insert(snap.value!, at: 0)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                     })
        }

        }})

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

You are setting all the time the same string here

> self.postingID = testingkey

so it is equal to the last element in the for cycle. For this reason in your if condition

> id == self.postingID

is true just for the last node

Maybe you want to change your self.postingID in an Array (or Set if the id is not already unique) and have something like:

```
var self.postingIdArray = [String]()
```

Then in you first function you want to append each key to this array

```
for testingkey in postsDictionary.keys {

        self.postingID = testingkey

    }
```

Eventually, you want to check if your node's id is in the array, like

```
if let id = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "id").value as? String, self.postingIdArray.contains(id) { self.posts.insert(snap, at: 0) }
```

OLD ANSWER

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("main")
let query = databaseRef.queryOrderedByKey()

query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                if snap.hasChildren() {
                    if let id = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "postId").value as? String, id == idToCompare {
                            print(id)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it prints out the ids I want but how to I get the values of these nodes?

Comment: child is what you mean with node. Try to print child instead of id and let me know

Comment: print(child) only prints out the last postID

Comment: so I have four postID i want to print out post1...post4, and it only prints the snapshot of post4

Comment: Post4 is the only one with children? If it's so, remove the last if condition

Comment: Have you tried to set an array instead of printing and then print the array outside the function?

Comment: set an array to id?

Comment: Something like 
if let id = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "postId").value as? String, id == idToCompare {
                           self.myPostArray.append(snap)
                    }

Comment: actually I didnt realise i had another print statement that was outputting all the postID i needed. The original post you made print(id) only prints out the last post, which is post4

Comment: sorry, im confused how do i correct it so that it is not only true for the last element but for all of them?

Comment: Thank you so much!! you just helped me out sooooo much after days of attempts!!

Comment: Well done! In case you are not able to see changes in your tableview, consider to add and observer to your posts array and in didSet tableview.reloadData() [assuming that your tableview is set, delegate and datasource are set and cellForRow is based on posts array]

Comment: i stupidly deleted tableview.reloadData() and forgot i did but it works now thanks!!